# How can I insert awgn noise in the eeg signal?

Tags: matlab

I have downloaded a file of .mat type and imported it in matlab, now I want to add noise in that eeg signal.

```
>fs = 512
>T = 1/fs; % sampling rate or frequency;
>N =length(EEGsig);
>ls = size(EEGsig); % find the length of the data per second
>tx =[0:length(EEGsig)-1]/fs;
>fx = fs*(0:N/2-1)/N;
>figure; subplot (211), plot(tx,EEGsig); xlabel('Time (s)'), 
>ylabel('Amplitude (uV)'), title('Original EEG signal');  %EEG waveform
>subplot(212), plot(tx,EEGsig);
>xlabel('Time (s)'), ylabel('Amplitude (uV)'), title('Zoom into original EEG 
signal at 1 to 2 seconds'), xlim([1,2]) ; % Used to zoom in on single ECG 
waveformfigure

<biomedical signal processing>
```

Comment: dear @rayryeng sir, i need to continue the code i have already mentioned above.and as i have just started using matlab,hence i really dont know to code with it

Comment: Have you read the duplicated question and it answers? If you think it doesn't solve your problem, please edit your post and clearly indicate the difference with the mentioned post.

Comment: @m7913d,sir m sorry for the misconvenience that yu had.as i am a beginner in matlab hence i'm unable to track out the errors or correct them.Thus,i had asked for help.